# setText method for EditText or TextView not working inside of switch statement

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, settext

I have two classes, one called SQLiteExample and it has a switch statement. in this switch is a button click listener where i want to read the resulting int into a TextView, this does not work.  i can read the int into a Toast message and display it with no errors.  however when reading it into a textview I don't know why it gets an error in the logcat when i do this.  the TextView is registered correctly.

```
 public class SQLiteExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 case R.id.bSQLnumberofrows:
        PlayGame ec = new PlayGame(this);
        ec.open();
        int x = ec.fetchPlacesCount();
        ec.close();
        showNumbers.setText(x);  // setText not working
                     // Toast message works perfectly and displays value of "x" on screen
        Toast.makeText(SQLiteExample.this, "value of x " + x , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
```

here is the logcat errors:

```
01-25 10:52:04.540: E/AndroidRuntime(8449): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 10:52:04.540: E/AndroidRuntime(8449): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5
01-25 10:52:04.540: E/AndroidRuntime(8449):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
01-25 10:52:04.540: E/AndroidRuntime(8449):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3473)
01-25 10:52:04.540: E/AndroidRuntime(8449):     at com.example.dbsample.SQLiteExample.onClick(SQLiteExample.java:127)
```

the line 127 is where the exception is: showNumbers.setText(x);

and the other class is PlayGame and has a method to get the number of rows in an SQLite database as an int:

```
 public class PlayGame {

 public int fetchPlacesCount() {
        int count = 0;
        Cursor q = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) from " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
        q.moveToFirst();
       count = q.getInt(0);
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the version of `setText()` which accepts an `int` parameter which is expected to refer to a string resource in an XML file. You need to convert your `int` to a `String` in order to display its value in a TextView. Note that you are doing this implicitly with `"value of x " + x` when using a Toast. You can explicitly convert an `int` into a `String` by calling `String.valueOf(x)`.

Comment: This indirectly solved another problem for me that I didn't realize after 4 hours of searching. Thank you!